# Story where telekinesis is used to stop nuclear bombs

Tags: story-identification, telekinesis

Does anyone remember the name of a story and the author where the USA uses telepaths/telekinesis to prevent Russian nuclear bomb from detonating?

Comment: Story? This is real life; http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1222369/Can-kill-goat-staring-eyes-Thats-plot-Hollywood-film-U-S-army-experiment.html

Comment: This also sounds somewhat like the first issue of the Global Frequency comic book, where a Russian psychic was supposed to use his psi powers to trigger a nuke in the US. Since the end of the cold war, the psychic had "gone native" and had no interest in blowing up California, but something's gone wrong with the outdated Soviet plot and he may not be able to stop his powers from firing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This happens in Robert Heinlein's 1953 short story [*Project Nightmare*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41032).  The bombs are not dropped, but are smuggled into the US and hidden in various places.  A team of psychics is used to locate the bombs and prevent them from exploding.

Spoiler:

> they don't get them all

Comment: That is it, I thought it was a Heinlein, in my memory of the story it just seemed like a Heinlein.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Done.  I had looked through my Heinlein short story collections before I asked but couldn't find it.  Problem was the collection it was in I was sure it would not be in.  It is in collection, "The Menace from Earth".  Though I suspect it is in others as well.  This site and those that frequent it are a great resource.  Thanks again.

Comment: If this is the same story I am thinking of, the issue is that some of the psychics appear to be sleeping when they are really working.  Someone doesn't realize this and goes to wake them up, thinking they are sleeping on the job...

Comment: That's right, one gets slapped to wake him up and loses his concentration.

Answer (score 11):

Could this be Kurt Vonnegut's ["The Report on the Barnhouse Effect"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Report_on_the_Barnhouse_Effect)?

It features a professor who discovers telekinesis and becomes the first "weapon with a conscience", choosing to disable all weapons as soon as they're exposed. The story is told from the viewpoint of an ex-student who follows in his footsteps.

> "Gentlemen," I read aloud, "As the first superweapon with a conscience, I am removing myself from your national defense stockpile. Setting a new precedent in the behavior of ordnance, I have humane reasons for going off. A. Barnhouse."

Comment: @user14111 quote added.

Answer (score 5):

Another one is the novel *Psychic Warrior* by Bob Mayer and Robert Doherty. Published in 2000

Both US and Soviet use psychic warriors. The title matches the book, it is the primary theme of the book. Bombs are "launched" via psi as well as stopped via psi battle.

Comment: Do you really think this could be the story the OP is seeking, even though he has accepted another answer? If this is just meant as a recommendation and not an answer to the question, it would be better as a comment.

Comment: No it is a different story (I saw the answer was already accepted). But it is an answer to the question as stated and may be the book someone else was looking for if they have the same question -- I figure answers are more likely to help someone else with the same question than a comment.