# Trying to identify 50s/60s story about nuclear weapons delivered to US cities by truck

Tags: story-identification, nuclear-weapons

This is a short story I remember reading in some anthology many years ago. The basic plot is that a nuclear adversary of the USA (it might have been China), lacking the necessary missile technology, instead delivers its nuclear weapons to multiple US cities by cargo truck. Once in place, they are all detonated with devastating effect, allowing the adversary to invade and conquer the smouldering remains of the US. I was reminded of this story by recent world events. However I've not been able to identify the story, which I think dated from the 1950s or thereabouts, or recall who the author was. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where's the link to Sci-Fi or fantasy? Nuclear weapons & trucks are both Sci-Reality.

Comment: That's a fair question - the link I suppose is simply that (as I remember) it was in an anthology of science fiction stories.

Comment: @AndrewThompson IF the story is from that time and I do not remember any like that, it would easily have been SCI-FI for that era as the means for accomplishing the task was not something someone would have considered "Reality" - Just pointing out that why would it not be fair to ask for a story that was SCI-FI but may no longer be considered SCI-FI now? I can think of several that would be very borderline now and probably, given time ... Ha ha, ok, I was taught that Only our Sun Had Planets as there was no evidence that Planets existed else where and even if they did we WOULD NEVER DETECT ..

Comment: THEM because the distance was far to great to allow for that. So now then any Story that involves travel to a distant Star would certainly run the risk of not being able to be queried here.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Let's simplify this for you Andrew, I am looking for a story written in the late 1800’s. I seem to remember this “During the year 1866, ships of several nations spot a mysterious sea monster, which some suggest to be a giant narwhal. The United States government assembles an expedition in New York City to find and destroy the monster. A French marine biologist and narrator of the story, who happens to be in New York at the time, receives a last-minute invitation to join the expedition which he accepts.”. Andrew says this is not SCIENCE FICTION anymore. Do you see my point?

Comment: could fall under post-apocolyptic a bit possibly, which may push it more to sci-fi standards. But I think I'd be ok w/ saying it is on topic for now given the era it's from (Twilight Zone-esque, etc...)

Comment: The opening of the Vernor Vinge short "The Whirligig of Time" has an attack in which "sneak 'em in" is used as part of a combined strategy with ballistic delivery. But the adversary is equivalent in tech, and the whole episode is just a prelude.

Comment: had another thought about on-topicness of OP - could fall under alternate history (a'la man in the high castle)

Comment: @NKCampbell but the issue is as highlighted by my extract from Jules Verne's "Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea" if this q/a disqualifies that title AS SCI-FI and all Verne titles then they have a very very very very long list of titles they must no longer accept as fit for this q/a Movies (Metropolis, Things to come) radio broadcast (War of the words, we know Mars is dead now so it can not be SCI-FI) Heinlein ... the list is enormous. In addition IF it disqualifies the past SCI-FI then they should in fact inform questioners of this and set the time frames that are acceptable.

Comment: @NKCampbell It is my opinion, that the very nature of this Q/A is to find PAST MEDIA as it is clear there can be no reasonable way to find FUTURE MEDIA and the need to find CURRENT MEDIA ... may be a very thin line (time wise)

Comment: @Andrew, Enigma: calm down and [be nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). I've removed both of your rude comments.

Comment: Could you be thinking of the Heinlein story Project Nightmare? I'm dubious because you don't mention the psi powers aspect, but take a look at this:: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81707/story-where-telekinesis-is-used-to-stop-nuclear-bombs

Comment: If the fictional date of the attack was before "now" which is January 10, 2018 as I write, then it happens in an alternate universe in which different historical events happened.  If the fictional date is still in the future, some people would consider all stories set in the future as science fiction, while others would demand science fictional events to make it science fiction.  IMHO the atomic bombs make it science fiction just as all real history since 1945 has also been science fiction.